# Pymssql Write to the server failed - 20006

Tags: sql-server, azure, pymssql

I am using pymssql=2.1.1 to connect Azure database from python. Due to idle connection for few minutes, i am getting error (Write to the server failed) and not able to fetch the data.

I am using connect method of pymssql to create connection to Azure DB.

```py
conn = pymssql.connect(server=v_host, user=v_user, password=v_passwd, database=v_db)
cursor = self.conn.cursor(as_dict=True)
cursor.execute(query)
```

The error looks like 
(20006, b'DB-Lib error message 20006, severity 9:\nWrite to the server failed\nNet-Lib error during Connection reset by peer (104)\n')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to us `pymssql` connect to Azure SQL database, make sure the following requirements:
[image]

Examples:

```
import pymssql
conn=pymssql.connect("xxx.database.windows.net", "username@xxx", "password", "db_name")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(query)
```

For more details, please see: [Connecting to Azure SQL Database](http://www.pymssql.org/en/stable/azure.html#connecting-to-azure-sql-database). Starting with version 2.1.1 pymssql can be used to connect to Microsoft Azure SQL Database. And you can troubleshoot the error by pymssql [Frequently asked questions](http://pymssql.org/en/latest/faq.html#cannot-connect-to-sql-server).

Another way, you also can try the `pyodbc` example:

```
import pyodbc
server = '<server>.database.windows.net'
database = '<database>'
username = '<username>'
password = '<password>'
driver= '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+server+';PORT=1433;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute(query)
```

Here is the Azure document: [Quickstart: Use Python to query an Azure SQL database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-python).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was facing issue sometimes when connection is idle for few minutes. Now i changed it to pyodbc and seems problem is solved.
Thanks for your pyodbc solution.

Comment: @Bhautik You're welcome.  If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.